# what's the type of the value assigned by $_GET['x'] and $_POST['x']?

Tags: php, string, web-applications, types, comparison

```
//include.php?filepath=theme.php (string)
//include.php?filepath=0 (int)
//include.php?filepath=[] (null)
$file = $_GET['filepath'];
if ($file != "theme.php")
{
   die("error file is not a theme");
}
include($file);
```

In the above code snippet what will be the comparison in line 2? String VS String or String VS Integer?

In other words what will `$_GET['x']` returns?

Comment: It's always a string

Comment: @YouneL can you give a proof of concept that's it's always the case? I couldn't find it anywhere in the documents

Comment: well, $_GET is an associative array resulted from a query string

Comment: @AK_, see [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) description page. It has a note, "The GET variables are passed through urldecode()". And the `urldecode` function always returns a sring.

Comment: @SergeyRonin this answers my question. Can you please post it as an answer with all the details and quotes along sources? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_GET` array always contains strings. When the query string is being processed by PHP, every variable in the query is passed through the [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function which always returns a string.

A note from the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable description:

> **Note:**
>
> The GET variables are passed through urldecode().

Answer (score 0):

In this link u can see that the super globals are of type string 
[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)